# No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashSet.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[README, INSTALL]]

Tags: gradle

Create file tree with project directory as base
directory and use method includes() on tree
object to include 2 files.

```
FileTree base = fileTree(".")
base.includes ['README', 'INSTALL']


 No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashSet.getAt() is applicable     
  for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[README,INSTALL]]
 Possible  solutions: getAt(java.lang.String),getAt(java.lang.String),getAt(int),     putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), wait(), first()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is correct, there's no such method. You need to use `addAll` e.g.:

```
FileTree base = fileTree(".")
println base.includes
base.includes.addAll(['README', 'INSTALL'])
println base.includes
```